# Spring boot Access-Control-Allow-Origin

Tags: angular, spring, spring-boot, spring-security, jwt

I have a problem when i try to call my backend with my angular client
I always have this error in post, put and delete methode:

```
Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'http://localhost:8087/categories' from origin 'http://localhost:4200' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: It does not have HTTP ok status.
```

Here is my backend

```
response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
    response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Origin, Accept, X-Requested-With, Content-Type,Access-Control-Request-Method, Access-Control-Request-Headers, credential, X-XSRF-TOKEN, authorization");
    response.setHeader("Access-Control-Expose-Headers", "Access-Control-Allow-Origin, Access-Control-Allow-Credentials, authorization");
    response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "POST, GET, OPTIONS, DELETE, PUT, PATCH");
    response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Credentials", "true");
    if (request.getMethod().equals("OPTIONS")) {
        response.setStatus(HttpServletResponse.SC_OK);
    }
```

I don't now why my client has been blocked

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is how I proceeded with my [Angular8-springboot](https://github.com/Georges73/ACCOUNT-FRONT-BACK-END) app.

I marked my controller with : `@CrossOrigin(origins = "http://localhost:4200")`

And this is my Cors config class.

```
@Component
public class SimpleCORSFilter implements Filter {

private final Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(SimpleCORSFilter.class);

public SimpleCORSFilter() {
    log.info("SimpleCORSFilter init");
}

@Override
public void doFilter(ServletRequest req, ServletResponse res, FilterChain chain) throws IOException, ServletException {

    HttpServletRequest request = (HttpServletRequest) req;
    HttpServletResponse response = (HttpServletResponse) res;

    response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", request.getHeader("Origin"));
    response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Credentials", "true");
    response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "POST, GET, OPTIONS, DELETE");
    response.setHeader("Access-Control-Max-Age", "3600");
    response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Content-Type, Accept, X-Requested-With, remember-me");

    chain.doFilter(req, res);
}

@Override
public void init(FilterConfig filterConfig) {
}

@Override
public void destroy() {
}

}
```